# MySQL performance on join on same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with 21 million records hosted on a 2Ghz 2GB GoDaddy VPS and I am wondering if I am at a hardware limitation or of there is a way for this query to be better optimized.

```sql
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT a.another_id ) 
FROM table a
INNER JOIN table b ON a.some_id =  '12384211026'
AND b.some_id =  '7961985974'
AND a.another_id = b.another_id
```

The query takes about 14 seconds to 2 minutes to run depending on the compared ID's.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE: Here is the schema**

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
    `id` BIGINT(55) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `another_id` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `category_id` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `category` VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
    `some_id` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `created_time` VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
    `processed` SMALLINT(2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `some` (`another_id`, `some_id`),
    INDEX `some_index` (`another_id`, `some_id`, `category_id`, `category`),
    FULLTEXT INDEX `name` (`name`),
FULLTEXT INDEX `some_id` (`some_id`),
    FULLTEXT INDEX `some_id` (`some_id`),
    FULLTEXT INDEX `category_id` (`category_id`),
    FULLTEXT INDEX `category` (`category`),
    FULLTEXT INDEX `created_time` (`created_time`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=23902326;
```

Comment: Make sure all the columns you're selecting or joining on are indexed.

Comment: Run `explain select count ...` to see where the problem is

Comment: You're saying you're joining on the same table, so table a **is** table b? If so, why are you joining?

Comment: Explain shows both rows Using Index under Extra's however the first show shows NULL for for possible keys, and the second row shows 4 keys available for index.

Why would the first one show NULL? If we are comparing on the same table, how could one say no keys, and the other say 4?

Comment: Post the schema of the tables please. We can provide a updated version that includes indexes. They allow MySQL to look up data in fields much faster. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: I added the schema as per tutu's request.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can be quite slow then joining based on multiple fields. 
Also your `DISTINCT` can be slower then a `GROUP`.

After making sure all the fields are indexed, try this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(`a`.`another_id`) 
FROM `table` AS `a` 
    INNER JOIN `table` AS `b` 
        ON `a`.`another_id` = `b`.`another_id` 
WHERE `a`.`some_id` = '12384211026' 
    AND `b`.`some_id` = '7961985974' 
GROUP BY `a`.`another_id`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the volume of data and the size of the hardware, your performance doesn't sound so bad.  I assume that you have an index on `table(some_id, another_id)`.  If not, try that index and see how the query works.

When asking performance questions about MySQL, it is a good idea to include the explain plan.  You can get this by putting `explain` in front of your query.

The following version of the query could, under some circumstances, be faster:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.another_id, min(t.some_id) as minid, max(t.some_id) as maxid
      from table t
      where t.some_id in ('12384211026', '7961985974')
      group by t.another_id
     ) t
where minid <> maxid;
```

One circumstance where this would be faster is when many rows from the two some_id's have the same value of another_id.